# Android application build options

Tags: android, xml

I am developing an application for two different clients.
The core of the application is the same, just the application launcher icon and the webservice urls are different.

xml for urls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="url">http://www.customer1_url.com/</string>
   <!-- <string name="url">http://www.customer2_url.com/</string> -->
</resources>
```

For the url I have to comment out one url everytime I built the application

Application manifest file:

```
   <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

As for the icon, I have to change the drawables in the res folder everytime when building.
**Is it possible to do this in a single project?**
I was wondering if there is a good way to realize this without going through my way of doing it.
I search in the internet the equivalent of `#ifdef` for xml file, and no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) for the common part and create different projects for specific client apps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Creating different projects is the only way?